# How can I change the length of primary key columns in all tables?

Tags: sql-server

We run into an annoying problem.
The task sounds really simple:
Our customer needs larger project numbers in our application. The application just needs some small changes in UI-Validation. So far, so fine.

Project numbers can be alphanumeric, so in our database, the number field is nvarchar(8) - badly, it's also the primary key of projects - don't ask me, who got that terrible idea ...

Because it is the primary key and projects belong to the most basic objects in our application, we got a lot of foreign keys referencing that stupid project number.

The number of referencing tables is not really stable from customer to customer - because a few customers got fewer modules activated, so they don't get all tables our application could have.

So we decided (in our childish minds), that we write some simple script / stored procedure, to change the length of the column and all of their references from nvarchar(8) to nvarchar(16) or something like that.

Sadly the SQL server moans, that there are depended on tables - because of the foreign keys. A fast google search leads to

```
execute ('alter table [' + @tschema + '].[' + @tname + '] nocheck constraint all');
```

That should deactivate the foreign keys, just for the moment, we wanna extend the project number.

The SQl server still give us these errors:

> ...
>   Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Das Objekt-Objekt
>   'PK_tblAnlagenProjekt' ist vom Spalte-Objekt 'ProjektNr' abhängig. Msg
>   5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Das Objekt-Objekt
>   'FK_tblAnlagenProjekt_tblProjekte' ist vom Spalte-Objekt 'ProjektNr'
>   abhängig.
>   ... all tables get the same error
>   ...

Our current stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ChangeProjektNrLength] @ProjektNrLength int
as
BEGIN

/* Disable foreign checks*/

declare @tname varchar(128), @tschema varchar(128);

declare tables cursor for
select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'tbl%';

open tables;

fetch next from tables
    into @tschema, @tname;

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
     execute ('alter table [' + @tschema + '].[' + @tname + '] nocheck constraint all');
fetch next from tables
    into @tschema, @tname;
end;

close tables;

deallocate tables;


/* Change column length */

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(max)

DECLARE c1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'ProjektNr'
    AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%view%'
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC

OPEN c1

FETCH NEXT FROM c1
INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

     DECLARE @SQL varchar(1000)

     SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @TableName + ' ALTER COLUMN ProjektNr    nvarchar(' + CAST(@ProjektNrLength as varchar) + ')'

     EXEC (@SQL)

     PRINT 'Changed Length of ProjektNr in table ' + @TableName + ' to ' + CAST(@ProjektNrLength as varchar)

     FETCH NEXT FROM c1
     INTO @TableName

 END

 CLOSE c1
 DEALLOCATE c1


 /* Enable foreign checks*/
 declare @tname2 varchar(128), @tschema2 varchar(128);

 declare tables cursor for
 select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'tbl%';

 open tables;

 fetch next from tables
     into @tschema2, @tname2;

 while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 begin
      execute ('alter table [' + @tschema2 + '].[' + @tname2 + '] check constraint all');
      fetch next from tables
      into @tschema2, @tname2;
 end;

 close tables;

 deallocate tables;

 END
```

When we change the column length directly in Microsoft SQL Management Studio with the help of the designer and uncheck in options the "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation", the studio tells us, that there are affected other tables and if we want to change them too - and it will do it. But we search a way, don't change the length in all ~50 tables manually ... if we missed some referenced columns, we could produce some bad-ass application errors in production time.

Has anyone some helpful hints for us?

Comment: so in summary you want to change the length of primary key (project number) for all tables

Comment: yes, i wanna change the project number (primary key) and all the foreign keys, which depends on that primary key

Comment: Just because the constraint is disabled, that doesn't mean you're allowed to change the column definitions. You have to remove the foreign keys completely then re-apply them afterwards.

Comment: so you wanna say: we must select all related foreign keys of the related tables, maybe save the names, source and target in a new temp-table, then dropping all the keys -> start to change the column length -> then read our temp-table and finally recreate dynamically the foreign keys? that's sounds funny - hoped for some option or something we can just deactivate

Comment: This [SCRIPT](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3347/drop-and-recreate-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sql-server/) should help you

Comment: that script could be the solution, thanks @TheGamesiswar we give it a try

Comment: Also, views with schemabinding option might be a problem. You will need to drop them as well (if you have any that use one of the primary key columns)

Comment: While you're doing this, you may want to estimate the impact of defining surrogate primary keys.  Probably a lot of work, but has some benefits (easier future refactors, potential performance impacts, etc).

Comment: It's an old application with a lot of stored procedures, we can't change to nice primary keys , just have to support it, till our redisign (new App with new Database) is ready